# Xamarin Log.v equivalent to print to console / logcat

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

How can I use Log.v() or an equivalent in Xamarin? I am developing an Android App in Xamarin/Visual Studio and I want to output some logs, e.g. like with Log.v() in Android, which i then can get via adb shell logcat. When I try to use

```
   Log.v("test");
```

Visual Studio states: ‚Log‘ is inaccessible to its protection level.

Debug.WriteLine(""); only writes to VS log, it does not appear in Logcat.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

**Update: Code added.**

```
        using Xamarin.Forms;
        using System;
        using System.Diagnostics;
        using Android.Util.Log;

        namespace xf2
        {
            public partial class xf2Page : ContentPage
            {
                public xf2Page()
                {
                    InitializeComponent();
                    Log.Debug("SO", "Debug");
                    Log.Error("SO", "Error");
                    Log.Info("SO", "Info");
                    Log.Warn("SO", "Warn");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: `using Android.Util;` not `using Android.Util.Log;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Log` is in the `Android.Util` namespace and is platform-specific.

```
using Android.Util;
```

Then you can use `Log` to output to logcat:

```
Log.Verbose("SO", "Verbose");
Log.Debug("SO", "Debug");
Log.Error("SO", "Error");
Log.Info("SO", "Info");
Log.Warn("SO", "Warn");
```

To call `Log` from a Forms-based PCL/NStd library, you could use a dependency service:

RE: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/

#### Dependency service Interface:

```
public interface ILogInterface
{
    void Verbose(string TAG, string message);
    void Info(string TAG, string message);
    void Debug(string TAG, string message);
    void Error(string TAG, string message);
    void Warn(string TAG, string message);
}
```

#### Android implementation:

```
public class LogImplementation : ILogInterface
{
    public void Debug(string TAG, string message)
    {
        L.Debug(TAG, message);
    }

    public void Error(string TAG, string message)
    {
        L.Error(TAG, message);
    }

    public void Info(string TAG, string message)
    {
        L.Info(TAG, message);
    }

    public void Verbose(string TAG, string message)
    {
        L.Verbose(TAG, message);
    }

    public void Warn(string TAG, string message)
    {
        L.Warn(TAG, message);
    }
}
```

Note: Apply the assembly-level dependency discovery attribute:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(ILogInterface))]
```

#### Forms Usage:

```
var Log = DependencyService.Get<ILogInterface>();
Log.Debug("SO", "record someting in logcat");
```

Comment: VS States to "using Android.Util": Using directive is unnecessary.
VS States to "Log.Info" and the others: ‚Log‘ is inaccessible to its protection level.

Comment: Then VS states: The name Android does not exist in the current context. Updated my code above, forgot to mention I am using Xamarin Forms for this. Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: @frazer87 Are you trying to use `Android.Util.Log` in a Forms-based PCL/NStd library? This is a platform-specific SDK, you would need to use a dependency service to access it from Forms.

Comment: That was exactly what I was trying to achieve. Works for me. Thank you very much!!